# Why vuetify tag isn't converted to html in browser?

Tags: html, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify in Nuxt 2 project and I have some issue with styles, so I checked that element in dev tools -> Inspect and I noticed that a few vuetify tags (markups) weren't converted to html (It always converts them to div class="tag_name"). And these tags were causing my issue with styles. Here's how it looks in dev tools:

[image]

What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

I checked my vuetify version in package.json, but there is no vuetify itself, only "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.12.1". In package-lock.json, I found the following versions of vuetify:

```
"@nuxtjs/vuetify": {
  "version": "1.12.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nuxtjs/vuetify/-/vuetify-1.12.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-oNwNhR6LY7l9ETsNyPkmCxgzbOYuAf27m+6E9mjQzHSu8PPI0vJ3xnGLgo87XnTcnWr9nYxqjwRN8xqMuuyoxQ==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.3",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.2"
  }
},
...
"vuetify": {
      "version": "2.7.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vuetify/-/vuetify-2.7.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-DVFmRsDtYrITw9yuGLwpFWngFYzEgk0KwloDCIV3+vhZw+NBFJOSzdbttbYmOwtqvQlhDxUyIRQolrRbSFAKlg==",
      "dev": true
    },
```

Comment: You can see vuetify version in package lock file

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask, I'm updating my question with that info

Comment: The cause is that v-list-tile component isn't registered for a reason. See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8701

Comment: @EstusFlask this solved my issue! Thanks, you can put it as an answer to get credits if you'd like :)

Comment: Sure, glad it was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That component elements appear in rendered HTML means that the components with the respected names weren't registered in Vue; there also may be a message in the console that warns about this.

In this case `v-list-tile` is Vuetify 1.x component, while Vuetify 2.x was used. As suggested in [the related issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8701), `v-list-tile*` components were renamed to `v-list-item*`.